# How to split a long formula and make it beautiful?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

My method:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \hat{c}_x(t,\gamma)=\int_0^t [K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma)+e_f(\sigma)] d\sigma \\
 & +K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t)-K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0) \\
 & -\int_0^t [\frac{\partial{K(\sigma,\gamma)}}{\partial \sigma}K_L e(\sigma)d\sigma
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, the formula becomes symmetrical.
    I want to know how to revise it.

Comment: I think you need to include a `&` on the first line. Try to add it between `=` and `\int_0^t` and see what happens.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice?

Comment: @egreg,Sorry, my network enviroment is bad ,so I gussess I  submit twice when I think it is not be submitted.

Answer (score 13):

You almost had it: you forgot to add `&` in the first row to mark the alignment point. A small refinement for not having the plus and minus below the equal sign by adding `\quad`. But I also present a slightly different approach, with the operation signs at the end of the lines.

Also, a `\,` before the differential is recommended

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \hat{c}_x(t,\gamma)&=\int_0^t [K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma)+e_f(\sigma)] \,d\sigma \\
 &\quad +K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t)-K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0) \\
 &\quad -\int_0^t \frac{\partial{K(\sigma,\gamma)}}{\partial \sigma}K_L e(\sigma) \,d\sigma
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \hat{c}_x(t,\gamma)={}
  &\int_0^t [K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma)+e_f(\sigma)] \,d\sigma + {} \\
  &K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t)-K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0) - {}\\
  &\int_0^t \frac{\partial{K(\sigma,\gamma)}}{\partial \sigma}K_L e(\sigma) \,d\sigma
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have the small space automatically added, type

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

and use `\diff\sigma` or `\diff x` when needed.

---

What's the difference between using

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

instead of

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
...
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{align*}
...
\end{align*}
```

that have been proposed?

With `split` you can globally act so that the number is centered or placed at the bottom (with equation numbers on the right, it would be at the top with equation numbers on the left). By default the number is vertically centered, but with

```
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
```

it would be placed at top or bottom.

With `aligned` you'd get it vertically centered no matter what option you give. With `align*` you get no number at all. If instead `align` is used, you'd have to place manually `\nonumber` on the non numbered lines and it would be awkward to center it for an even number of lines.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, I meant that.

Comment: The main problem I see with the *slightly different approach, with the operation signs at the end of the lines* is that is a bit baffling. For example, the last line, your mind (at least mine) clearly “adds it to the sum” while you should subtract it (because of the minus). The benefit of the operation signs at the beginning is that it's a mix of *unary* and *binary* operators and clarifies the expression.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are after something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \hat c_x(t,\gamma) &= \int_0^t \Bigl[
    K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma) + e_f(\sigma)
  \Bigr] d\sigma
  \\
  & \qquad {}+ K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t) - K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0)
  \\
  & \qquad {}- \int_0^t \Bigl[ \frac{\partial K(\sigma,\gamma)}{\partial\sigma}
    K_L e(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \hat c_x(t,\gamma)
  &= \int_0^t [K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma) + e_f(\sigma)] \dif\sigma \\
  &\hphantom{{}=} + K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t) - K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0) \\
  &\hphantom{{}=} - \int_0^t \left[ \frac{\partial K(\sigma,\gamma)}{\partial\sigma} K_L e(\sigma)\right] \dif\sigma
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

## Remarks

I'm amazed, that no one suggested `multline`.

I prepared an example using three different approaches:

- `multine`: Left align the first line, mid aligns the lines in between and right aligns the last line.
- `multlined` (requires the `mathtools` package): Similar to `multine`, but to be used inside of e.g. `equation`, just like `aligned`. It aligns the last line a little behind the end of the first line, the lines in between will be aligned to the center.
- `dmath` from the `breqn` package: The `breqn` package features automatic linebreaking of equation, but has many downsides!

## Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath, provides multlined
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
    \hat c_x(t,\gamma)
    = \int_0^t \Bigl[ K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma) + e_f(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma \\
    + K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t) - K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0)\\
    - \int_0^t \Bigl[ \frac{\partial K(\sigma,\gamma)}{\partial\sigma} K_L e(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma
\end{multline*}
\clearpage
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{multlined}
        \hat c_x(t,\gamma)
        = \int_0^t \Bigl[ K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma) + e_f(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma \\
        + K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t) - K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0)\\
        - \int_0^t \Bigl[ \frac{\partial K(\sigma,\gamma)}{\partial\sigma} K_L e(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma
    \end{multlined}
\end{equation*}
\clearpage
\begin{dmath*}% no line breaks with \\ needed.
    \hat c_x(t,\gamma)
    = \int_0^t \Bigl[ K(\sigma,\gamma) K_L(e_\sigma) + e_f(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma
    + K(t,\gamma) K_L e(t) - K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0)
    - \int_0^t \Bigl[ \frac{\partial K(\sigma,\gamma)}{\partial\sigma} K_L e(\sigma) \Bigr] d\sigma
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

## `multline`

[image]

## `multlined`

[image]

## `breqn`

[image]

Comment: A nice juxtaposition of various possible solutions. I think it might be even more useful if three solutions were rendered with the same magnification. (Right now, the effective font sizes are rather different.)

Comment: @Mico I will try to correct it, but this is due to the upload, where the StackExchange-software scales the picture to fit the column width.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not only ask for line-breaking but also about beautification, I would like to add the following suggestions extending another answer:

1. In case "L" is not a variable, it should not be written italic.
2. I saw an upright "d" in many publications. You could consider to set it upright as well. Many people also prefer a half space in front of it.

Pick or ignore this suggestions depending on your focused audience.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \hat c_x(t,\gamma) &= \int\limits_0^t \Bigl[
    K(\sigma,\gamma) K_{\mathrm L}(e_\sigma) + e_f(\sigma)
  \Bigr] \mathrm d\sigma
  \\
  & \qquad {}+ K(t,\gamma) K_{\mathrm L} e(t) - K(0,\gamma) K_L e(0)
  \\
  & \qquad {}- \int\limits_0^t \Bigl[ \frac{\partial K(\sigma,\gamma)}{\partial\sigma}
    K_{\mathrm L} e(\sigma) \Bigr] \mathrm d\sigma
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Interpreted LaTeX source]